# Angular 5 - Component with ngIf creating duplicates instead of toggle

Tags: angular, toggle, angular5, angular-ng-if

I am attempting to make a reusable component that basically toggles from one icon to another icon when clicked. I have attempted it with and without using ng-template, using *ngIf, and using switch case.

EDITED BASED ON COMMENT

Here is my example:

**Icon Toggle Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-icon-toggle',
    template: `    
        <a [ngClass]="iconStyle" [ngSwitch]="active">
            <i *ngSwitchCase="true" class="fa {{activeIcon}}"></i>
            <i *ngSwitchCase="false" class="fa {{inactiveIcon}}"></i>
        </a>
    `
})
export class IconToggleComponent implements AfterContentChecked {

    @Input() active: boolean;

    @Input() activeIcon: string;
    @Input() inactiveIcon: string;

    @Input() iconStyle: string;

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
      console.log('content check', this.active);
    }
}
```

**Component using it**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-info-toggle',
  template: `
      <template #loading><i></i></template>

      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: start;">

      <app-icon-toggle [active]="showChangeInfo" 
                       [activeIcon]="'fa-eye'" 
                       [inactiveIcon]="'fa-eye-slash'" 
                       [iconStyle]="'show-change-info'" 
                       (click)="toggleShowChangeInfo()">
      </app-icon-toggle>

      <!-- ORIGINAL SETUP THAT I AM EXTRACTING -->
      <div *ngIf="lockEditing; then editIcon else lockIcon"></div>

      <ng-template #editIcon>
          <a class="change-lock" (click)="toggleEdit()">
              <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
          </a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #lockIcon>
          <a class="change-lock" (click)="toggleEdit()">
              <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          </a>
      </ng-template>
  </div>
`
})
export class AdminInfoToggleComponent implements OnInit {
    lockEditing = true;
    showChangeInfo = true;

    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sessionService.getLockEditing()
            .subscribe(isLocked => this.lockEditing = isLocked);
    }

    toggleEdit() {
       this.sessionService.toggleEditingLock(this.lockEditing)
             .subscribe(isLocked => this.lockEditing = isLocked);
    }

    toggleShowChangeInfo() {
        this.showChangeInfo = !this.showChangeInfo;
    }
}
```

**Session Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionService implements OnInit {

      lockEditing = new Subject<boolean>();

      ngOnInit(): void {
          this.lockEditing.next(true);
      }

      getLockEditing() {
        return this.lockEditing;
      }

      toggleEditingLock(isLocked: boolean) {
          this.lockEditing.next(!isLocked);

          this.lockEditing.subscribe(isLocked => 
              console.log('toggleEditingLock [result]', isLocked));

          return this.lockEditing;
      }
}
```

I guess it wants more details since it is only code.

[Duplicating icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah2f3.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is have a service that houses a variable called like 'toggled' and in your icon toggle component set the toggled variable in the service to true or false depending on the state. Then in your component using the toggle you subscribe to the value of toggled in the service and then do an *ngIf to specify whether the object should be shown or not.

For instance:

**Icon Toggle Component**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-icon-toggle',
    template: `    
        <a [ngClass]="iconStyle" [ngSwitch]="active" (click)="inputPressed()">
            <i *ngSwitchCase="true" class="fa {{activeIcon}}"></i>
            <i *ngSwitchCase="false" class="fa {{inactiveIcon}}"></i>
        </a>
    `
})
export class IconToggleComponent implements AfterContentChecked {
    
    constructor(inputService: InputService) {}
    
    inputPressed() {
     this.inputService.inputValChanged.next(!this.inputVal);
    }

    @Input() active: boolean;

    @Input() activeIcon: string;
    @Input() inactiveIcon: string;

    @Input() iconStyle: string;

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
      console.log('content check', this.active);
    }
}
```

**Icon Service**

```js
export service IconService {

            inputVal = true;
            inputChanged: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>;
            
            inputValChanged() {
               this.inputChanged.next(!inputVal);
               this.inputVal = !this.inputVal;
            }
        }
```

**Component to Be Toggled**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-icon-toggle',
    template: <div *ngIf="currentInputVal"></div>
})
export class ComponentToBeToggeld implements OnIt {

    currentInputVal;
    currentValSubscription;

    constructor(inputService: InputService) {
      this.currentValSubscription = this.inputValChanged(val => {
         this.currentInputVal = val;  
      });
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: I was not in front of an environment to work on so this is the gist of how to answer the question but some things might be a little off

Comment: I actually have something like that but it is resulting in the same behavior. When I get a chance I will make a plunkr but with my luck it will work just fine.

Not sure if I am doing it wrong or if it is some obscure bug.

Comment: None. Everything is working correctly (even consoles the correct locking boolean value). I am wondering why it is making multiple copies when I only have 2 possible states declared. Seems like the dom isn't destroying the element on value change. I will add a screenshot of the results of clicking on it at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You could set the dom elements to have a style='display: none' property maybe?